# stop a thread in java after a given time - doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a complex function (optimisation) that can potentially enter in a loop or just to take too much time, and the time allowed is set by the user.

Therefore I am trying to make to run the function in a separate thread, and to stop it if the maximum time is passed. I use a code similar to the one below, but it doesn't work, so

```
int timeMax = 2; //time in minutes  
Thread Thread_Object = new Thread_Class(... args...);
try {
  Thread_Object.start();
  Thread_Object.join(timeMax*60*1000);
}
```

I think that I'm not using the function "join" properly, or it doesn't do what I have understood. Any idea?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the answers, currently I have found a better idea here*. It works but it still uses the function "stop" that is deprecated. The new code is:

```
Thread Thread_Object = new Thread_Class(... args...);

try {
  int timeMax = 1;
  Thread_Object.start();
  Thread.currentThread().sleep( timeMax * 1000 );

    if ( Thread_Object.isAlive() ) {
        Thread_Object.stop();
        Thread_Object.join();
    }

}
catch (InterruptedException e) {

}
```

not yet sure of the function of "join", I'll have to go to have a look at some book.

- [java scripting API - how to stop the evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601246/java-scripting-api-how-to-stop-the-evaluation/1601465#1601465)

Comment: Dont't use `Thread.stop()`. It can leave shared data in an inconsistent state. If you're not going to use a `Timer`, I suggest you do what John V said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use a [Timer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html).

Comment: This is probably the right construct for whatever problem requires this capability.

Comment: @Amir - I cannot argue with that!

Comment: done it, but I've used a ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate.

Answer (score 3):

The join method will wait the current thread until the thread that is being joined on finishes.  The join with milliseconds passed in as a parameter will wait for some amount of time, if the time elapses notify the waiting thread and return.

What you can do, is after the join completes interrupt the thread you joined on.  Of course this requires your thread to be responsive to thread interruption.

Comment: `interrupt()` only works if thread is waiting (is blocked by `wait(..)` or `join(..)`).

Comment: That is under the assumption you don't write code that handles interruption.  You can easily have a check if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){ thread.interrupt(); return; }

Comment: Please read: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()

Comment: If a thread calls `wait()` or `join()` (on another thread) it can be externally interrupted by `interrupt()`. Otoh, if it is doing some work, than `interrupt()` will do nothing.

Comment: Peter, your  resolution is to have a boolean flag to be set if the thread should stop.  Would testing to see if a thread is interrupted be the same thing?

Comment: Not entirely: you need to check the flag with `interrupted()` (warrning: this clears the flag), AND handle `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Though that is true, you are not taking into account my previous comment.  I specifically said if he checks Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() then he can assume the thread should be stopped.  Its also important to know isInterrupted() does NOT effect the interruption status

Comment: Interruption status is not set if thread is inside `wait()` - the docu link I posted explains this. Note that `wait()` is used by most InputStream operations waiting for data. In this case thread will get `InterruptedException` but no interruption flag will be set. So, he must check both interruption flag AND catch `InterruptedException`.

Comment: Of course he has to handle InterruptedException. That goes in hand to what I said when I mentioned he has to be responsive to interruption. My solution is still more effective to the single flag, because if his thread is waiting setting the flag to true will do nothing to stop the thread

Comment: And at that point the exception is thrown he now knows the thread is interrupted and can leave the thread accordingly

Answer (score 1):

[`Thread.join(milis)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29) does not kill the thread. It just waits for the thread to end.

Java threading is cooperative: you can not stop or gracefully kill a thread without it's cooperation. One way to do it is to have an atomic flag (boolean field) that thread is checking and exiting if set.

Answer (score 1):

Watchdog-Timers in Java are not a simple thing, since threading is cooperative. I remember that in one project we just used Thread.stop() although it is deprecated, but there was no elegant solution. We didn't face any issues using it, though.

A good example for a Java Watchdog implementation:

http://everything2.com/user/Pyrogenic/writeups/Watchdog+timer

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful

http://tempus-fugit.googlecode.com/svn/site/documentation/concurrency.html#Scheduled_Interruption